# I get an error when installing ibm_db with pip

Tags: python

pip version 22.0.4 and python 3.10.4

The end of the error message looks like this:

```
copying README.md -> build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages
      copying CHANGES.md -> build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages
      copying LICENSE -> build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages
      copying config.py.sample -> build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages
      error: could not create 'build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\config.py.sample': No such file or directory
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for ibm_db

Failed to build ibm_db

ERROR: Could not build wheels for ibm_db, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

**Edit**: I will copy the start of the error message below since the whole message is too long. The wheel package is installed (tried to run pip install wheel).

```
Collecting ibm_db
  Using cached ibm_db-3.1.1.tar.gz (1.1 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: ibm_db
  Building wheel for ibm_db (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for ibm_db (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [785 lines of output]
      Detected 64-bit Python
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib
      copying ibm_db_dbi.py -> build\lib
      copying testfunctions.py -> build\lib
      copying tests.py -> build\lib
      copying ibm_db.py -> build\lib
      creating build\lib\certs
      copying certs\__init__.py -> build\lib\certs
      creating build\lib\clidriver
      copying clidriver\__init__.py -> build\lib\clidriver
      creating build\lib\ibm_db_dlls
      copying ibm_db_dlls\__init__.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_dlls
      creating build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_000_PrepareDb.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_001_ConnDb.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_002_ConnDbUncatalogedConn.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_003_NumAffectedRows.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_004_ConnWrongUserPwd.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_005_ConnBadUserBadPwd.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_006_ConnPassingOpts.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_007_pConnPassingOpts.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_008_ColumnInfo.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_010_UpdateRowCount.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_011_DeleteRowCount.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_012_KeysetDrivenCursorSelect01.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_013_KeysetDrivenCursorSelect02.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_014_KeysetDrivenCursorNegativeRow.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_015_InsertDeleteRowCount_01.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_016_InsertDeleteRowCount_02.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_017_selectRowcountPrefetchSTMTOpt.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_018_selectRowcountPrefetchSetOpt.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_019_selectRowcountPrefetchPrepOpt.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_020_RollbackDelete.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_021_CommitDelete.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_022_RollbackInsert.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_023_ColumnPrivileges.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_024_ForeignKeys.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_025_PrimaryKeys.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_030_Result.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_031_ResultIndexPosition.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_032_ResultIndexName.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_033_ResultOutSequenceColumn.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_034_FetchAssoc.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_035_FetchRow_01.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_036_FetchRow_02.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_037_FetchRowIndexPos.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_038_FetchRowIndexPosNested_01.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_039_FetchRowIndexPosNested_02.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_03a_ResultNonExistCol.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_040_FetchTuple.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_041_FetchTupleMany_01.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_042_FetchTupleMany_02.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_043_FetchTupleMany_03.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_044_FetchTupleMany_04.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_045_FetchTupleBinaryData_01.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_046_FetchTupleMany_05.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_047_FetchTupleMany_06.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_048_FetchTupleBinaryData_02.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_049_InsertNoneParam.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_050_AutocommitStatus.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_051_SetAutocommit_01.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_052_SetAutocommit_02.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_053_AttrThruConn.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_054_CursorType.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_060_Tables_01.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_061_Tables_02.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_062_Tables_03.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_063_Tables_04.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
      copying ibm_db_tests\test_064_Tables_05.py -> build\lib\ibm_db_tests
```

Then it just goes on to copying more files.

Comment: Could you maybe include the full error message..?

Comment: You may be missing the `wheel` package, or you may be missing dependencies to build the package. That is unclear from the error message currently shown.

Comment: The ibm_db page claims that there are prebuilt binaries for Windows (32 and 64 bit), for Python 3.10. But the "Failed building wheel" error message suggests differently. You may want to take this up on the [ibm_db GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/issues).

Comment: @9769953 They claim there are wheels, but there aren't, not on PyPI anyway... :)

Comment: @AKX I know: it was where I looked. Which is why I think this should be taken up on GitHub, since this seems to a specific ibm_db issue.